# Enable/ Disable for the textfield with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two field named  "Input1" and "Input2" with id as "inputID". 
If I click "Input1" field,Input2 field to be disable. 
And after reset, If I click "Input2" field,Text" Input1 should be disable. 
I can able to achieve this by different id in javascript. But I need to get this with same id.
Can anyone please me on this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunc1() {
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2= document.getElementById("input2");
if (input1.click){
  document.getElementById("input2").disabled=true;
 } 
}
function myFunc2() {
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2= document.getElementById("input2");

if (input2.click) {
  document.getElementById("input1").disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Field1: <input type="text" id="input1" onclick="myFunc1();" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Field2  : <input type="text" id="input1" onclick="myFunc2();" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Id's are supposed to be unique. The whole point of an Id is to give the element a UNIQUE identifier.

Comment: Id's must be unique-- but you could target with classes instead...

Comment: bind an onchange event to both of the inputs in which you check if its not empty and add the disabled attribute and if it is empty remove the disabled attribute simple as that.

Comment: you are almost there, just add two different classes and modify your code little bit. Why to try fancy jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, the id's should be unique, but if you insist on doing this the way you have it planned now, just get the elements by name since they are unique.

```
function myFunc1() {
var input1 = document.getElementsByName("input1");
var input2= document.getElementsByName("input2");
if (input1.click){
  input2.disabled=true;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works, however if you want to make it really dynamic and clean, I'd make a function like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function() {

  $("input[type=text]").not(this).attr("disabled", true);

});


$("button#reset").click(function() {

  $("input[type=text]").attr("disabled", false);

});
```

This targets all `input[type=text]` except the one you clicked. Pretty simple and very little code.

***DEMO http://jsbin.com/kegasehagi/edit?html,js,console,output***

Comment: Nice answer. i was actually just about to update my answer to suggest a "cleaner" approach in addition to my original answer.

Comment: @user1289451 Thanks! Good thing about javascript is that you can accomplish things many different ways. Bad thing about javascript is that you can accomplish things many different ways...haha js can get real messy if you're not careful.

Comment: Agreed. One thing I've noticed about SO is that when most people ask questions, they are put off by significant changes to their code. So, I usually try to answer in a way that matches the structure of their code as close as possible. Even if it's not the way I would write it. But suggesting a better approach is always helpful.

Comment: @user1289451 Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/vv3wkftj/17/) for you in pure Jquery.

```
$(function(){
$('input[type=text]').click(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       if(!($(this).is(":focus"))){
         $(this).attr('disabled',true);
       }
    });
});

});
```

But, I would suggest you to keep IDs different and use class instead.

I hope, It will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can add more inputs with class name inpu and it will works.

**Pure JavaScript:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>test page</title></head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Field1: <input type="text" class='inpu' onclick="focusonly(this);" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Field2  : <input type="text" class='inpu' onclick="focusonly(this);" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Field3  : <input type="text" class='inpu' onclick="focusonly(this);" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Field4  : <input type="text" class='inpu' onclick="focusonly(this);" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button onclick='reset();'>reset</button></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    <script>
    function reset(){
    var inpu = document.getElementsByClassName("inpu");
    for(var i=0;i<inpu.length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("inpu")[i].value = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName("inpu")[i].disabled = false;
    }
    }
    function focusonly(el){
    var inpu = document.getElementsByClassName("inpu");
    for(var i=0;i<inpu.length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("inpu")[i].disabled = true;
    }
    el.disabled = false;
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```